# CSS :before on inline SVG

Tags: css, html, svg, pseudo-element

**Update** 
Thanks porneL for pointing out the relation between generated content and replaced elements.
I found [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20170103232556/http://red-team-design.com/css-generated-content-replaced-elements/) which deals with this very topic:

Interestingly enough, a W3C document titled "CSS3 Generated and Replaced Content Module" (from 11 years ago!) defines the pseudo-element `:outside`, which could offer a solution to using generated content with replaced elements, by placing the generated content outside the replaced element, instead of trying to append it inside.

---

**Original question**

**Is there a way to style an inline SVG element using the CSS `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements?**

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wD56Q/

In this example, the styling defined with `:before` is not applied to the SVG (tested in Firefox 29 and Chrome 35).
Is it about the `content` property in `:before`? For what I read, it tries to insert a generated content in the element.. is it what fails with SVG?

Related documentation from MDN:

> **::before (:before)**

> ::before creates a pseudo-element that is the first child of the
> element matched. Often used to add cosmetic content to an element, by
> using the content property. This element is inline by default.

> **content**

> The content CSS property is used with the ::before and ::after
> pseudo-elements to generate content in an element. Objects inserted
> using the content property are anonymous replaced elements.

The code in the example:

```css
   svg {
     left: 50px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50px;
   }
   svg circle {
     fill: green;
   }
   svg:before {
     border: 2px solid blue;
     content: "";
     height: 100px;
     margin: -6px;
     padding: 4px;
     position: absolute;
     width: 100px;
     z-index: -1;
   }
   div {
     background-color: green;
     height: 100px;
     left: 200px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 150px;
     width: 100px;
   }
   div:before {
     border: 2px solid blue;
     content: "";
     height: 100px;
     margin: -6px;
     padding: 4px;
     position: absolute;
     width: 100px;
     z-index: -1;
   }
```

```html
<svg height="100" width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
</svg>

<div></div>
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

No, inline SVG is treated as an image, and images are *replaced elements* which are not allowed to have *generated content*.

Strictly speaking, I think it's undefined. [CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/conform.html) just talks about "images, embedded documents and applets" in general and [The HTML standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/rendering.html#images-0) defines it for images, but not SVG explicitly.

Comment: Strictly speaking a `<button>` element *can* contain generated content; it's `input` elements (including those of `type="button"`) that cannot.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! The article I linked in the update references a counter example, where Chrome allows for `:after` on an `input` element. They note, however, that this is probably not an intended behavior.

Comment: From MDN: "In CSS, a replaced element is an element whose representation is outside the scope of CSS. These are kind of external objects whose representation is independant of the CSS." - Although I never found SVG mentioned as an example, it should fall into this category.

Comment: If inline SVG is treated as images, then why can I use CSS in my HTML document to style individual parts of my inline SVG?

Comment: @DavidThomas could you please clarify your point? Does SVG allow setting content by CSS for certain elements?

Comment: Is this is still true in 2022?

Comment: As best I can tell [through testing](https://jsfiddle.net/ad0h3m9o/1/show), no, you can't use `::before` or `::after` with svg. In chrome, the pseudo element shows up in the DOM in the dev tools, but I can't make it visibly show up on screen.