# Append css to svg in D3

Tags: svg, d3.js

Am newbie to d3.I am trying to add some bubble feature to circle which is drwan in d3.I have added CSS  to achive bubble effect.
I have inspect the element css is added to the circle but bubble effet is not reflecting. 
Thanks in Advance

```
<style type="text/css">
.ball {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 120%, #81e8f6, #76deef 10%, #055194 80%, #062745 100%);
}
.ball:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 1%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 0px, #ffffff, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 58%);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  z-index: -1;
}

.ball .shadow {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 40%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%);
-webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(-150px);
-moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(-150px);
-ms-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(-150px);
-o-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(-150px);
transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(-150px);
z-index: -1;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

circleRadii = [40]

 svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg");


    gcontainer=svgContainer.append("g").attr("width", 600)
                                    .attr("height", 100);

var circles = gcontainer.selectAll("circle")
                          .append("g")
                          .data(circleRadii)
                          .enter()
                          .append("circle")

var circleAttributes = circles
                       .attr("cx", 50)
                       .attr("cy", 50)
                       .attr("r", function (d) { return d; })
                       .style("fill", "green")
                       .attr("class","ball");

</script>
```

Comment: there is no such things as `:before` in svg elements.

Answer (score 1):

> Inline SVG is treated as an image, and images are replaced elements which are not allowed to have generated content.

[CSS :before on inline SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026458/css-before-on-inline-svg)

> The before and after pseudo-selectors don't insert HTML elements — they insert text before or after the existing content of the targeted element. Because image elements don't contain text or have descendants, neither img:before or img:after will do you any good.

[Does :before not work on img elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843035/does-before-not-work-on-img-elements)

This may also help you out:

[SVG drop shadow using css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088409/svg-drop-shadow-using-css3)

[SVG gradient using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051351/svg-gradient-using-css)