# How to insert material icon directly into svg element in vue

Tags: html, css, svg, vue-material

I have a svg element, and I would like to insert a material icon inside.

Like 
[How do I include a font awesome icon in my svg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984007/how-do-i-include-a-font-awesome-icon-in-my-svg) 
but in Vue with material icons

That code doesn't work

html:

```
<svg >
  <circle class="background" cx="50%" cy="50%" r=100></circle>
  <text class="icon" x="50%" y="50%" >dashboard</text>
</svg>
```

and css:

```
.icon {
  font-family: "Material Icons";
}
```

but that code outside from svg element works:

```
<div style="font-family: Material Icons;">settings</div>
```

Comment: Please try `<svg viewBox ="0 0 200 200" width="200">
  <circle class="background" cx="50%" cy="50%" r=100></circle>
  <text class="icon" x="50%" y="50%" >dashboard</text>
</svg>` and in CSS use `.background{fill:none; stroke:black;}` Let me know if this is what you need.

Comment: It makes me an empty item with background. I've already try that but I have removed for the post to provide clearer example.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried inside your .svg?  I still had to include the material icons link in the head of the html doc that used it, but it did just finally now work for me.

```svg
    <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20">
        <div style="font-family: Material Icons;">settings</div>
    </foreignObject>
```

Comment: I couldn't get text displayed on my SVG with foreignObject for some reason. I used the inline styling to get this to work `currentText.attr('style', "font-family: Material Icons;"); currentText.text('flag');`

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because the style sheet is not loaded first, before the SVG? If that's the case, using

```
style="font-family: Material Icons;
```

Should just work on the text element.

If the CSS is loaded before, I think that this answer might be able to provide you with some insight:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30229965/2523968