# SVG: Set <text> content with CSS

Tags: css, svg

Can I

```
<svg>
  <text></text>
</svg>

svg text {
  content: 'a';
  font-family: 'Glyphicon Halflings';
}
```

?

It seems `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements are not available, but I would be very happy to have my content set by css. Can I?

Comment: Related (and possibly even a dupe) of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026458/css-before-on-inline-svg

Comment: Have you tried it? That would seem to be the most obvious thing to do.

Comment: I have tried my example, it doesn't work (`content` only works for `:before` and `:after`, which are not available in `svg` thanks to Harry's [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026458/css-before-on-inline-svg)). But there are other keys in CSS svg that don't exist in traditional CSS (eg. `fill`, `stroke`), so maybe there is one that sets the `<text>` content?

Comment: So simply...the answer is "no"...you can't.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible using pure CSS. Need to use simple JS:

```
function changeMyText()
{
    document.getElementById('MyText').textContent = "new text";
}
```

and create ID for your SVG text:

```
<svg>
    <text id="MyText"></text>
</svg>
```