# Is it possible to have the same svg but with different text?

Tags: html, css, button, svg, menu

For example, I want to create a menu, but instead of css buttons, I'm using a SVG which I add it as an object. I add it 4 times (e.g. Home, Store, About, Contact). So: 4 objects, same SVG button. Is it possible to add text for each button if I'm using only one SVG file?

HTML

```
<div id="first">
  <div>
    <object data="skillItem.svg" class="skillItemSVG" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#first  skillItemSVG:before { content: "Home"; }
```

SVG file skillItem.svg

```
<svg version="1.1" id="skillItem" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="120px" height="90px" viewBox="0 0 120 90" enable-background="new 0 0 120 90" xml:space="preserve">
    <defs>
        <style type="text/css">
            #skillTagBg {
                opacity: 0;
            }

            .hoverItem {
                transition: 0.3s ease-out;
            }

            a {
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            a:hover .hoverItem {
                fill: #a8d500;
            }
        </style>
    </defs>
    <a href="#">
        <path class="hoverItem" id="skillTag" fill="#ADADAD" d="M108,0H0v55h120V12L108,0z M119,54H1V1h106.2L119,12.6V54z"/>
        <g id="SkillButton">
            <path class="hoverItem" id="button" fill="#ADADAD" d="M115.3,90H4.7C2.1,90,0,87.9,0,85.3V64.7C0,62.1,2.1,60,4.7,60h110.6c2.6,0,4.7,2.1,4.7,4.7
        v20.6C120,87.9,117.9,90,115.3,90z"/>
        </g>
        <polygon id="skillTagBg" fill="#ADADAD" points="1,1 1,54 119,54 119,12.6 107.2,1 "/>
    </a>
</svg>
```

Comment: You could create it all from some kind of template with javascript.

Comment: Can you provide a code example of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you probably can (for instance, using [CSS `content` property](https://css-tricks.com/css-content/)), but without JavaScript those will be bad solutions. Since you haven't provide your SVG, I'll give you and idea in just XML + CSS and you then can try it with your SVG:

XML (to use semantic tags to illustrate the idea):

```
<someHtmlWrapper id="first">
    <yourSVG>
        <theButton></theButton>
    </yourSVG>
</someHtmlWrapper>
<someHtmlWrapper id="second">
    <yourSVG>
        <theButton></theButton>
    </yourSVG>
</someHtmlWrapper>
```

CSS:

```
#first  theButton:before { content: "Home"; }
#second theButton:before { content: "Store"; }
```

This is straight-forward: the wrapper id allows you to create a distinct selector, the only question is whether the `content` property is applicable to the SVG element that you want to fill with text.

Comment: Sorry for the late respond. Had some things to take care of. So, I tried this:     

  <div id="first">
      <div>
          <object data="skillItem.svg" class="skillItemSVG" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
      </div>
  </div>

And it's not working your way. :(

Comment: @tc9 please show your SVG (probably better in your initial post) and CSS you've tried for this approach

Comment: @tc9 right, so your current CSS is not "correct": you have the `skillItemSVG` descendant selector, but you only have an element with skillItemSVG class, hence `.skillItemSVG` is needed. But even that is not good enough: `.skillItemSVG` will select the `object` element while you need to add the text to a certain place in your SVG (inside the polygone above or the rectangle below?). But the approach I suggested may not work anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31608129/svg-set-text-content-with-css (this needs some more research)