# Using pseudo-elements on SVG sub-elements

Tags: html, css, svg

I currently have an SVG which is a map of the UK, I've added some circle elements to the SVG which will be used as location markers.

```
<circle id="newcastle" cx="123.79" cy="152.28" r="2" fill="#ff671f"></circle>
```

Ideally, I was hoping to use the selector

```
#newcastle:hover::after { ... }
```

to create a pseudo-element when the user hovers over the location marker, but this doesn't appear to be working.

I've had a look online but most articles seem to be related to using SVGs in pseudo-elements and not the other way round. Is it currently possible to add pseudo-elements to SVG elements or is this not within spec? If not, are there any workarounds for achieving this effect?

Comment: No, that's not possible. You could create a hidden element and then show it on hover.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do you may not need the pseudo-element at all. You may be able to change the styles directly with CSS (at least in some broswers).

Comment: `:before` and `:after` do not currently work on SVG elements.

Comment: Might be of intereset: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24026800/802365

Answer (score 0):

The :before and :after pseudo-elements do not work for elements inside a SVG tag.
See [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle)