# Does the :before pseudo-class affect tspan in SVG?

Tags: css, svg, font-awesome

Can I use a :before CSS pseudo-element with an SVG tspan element?

Specifically, I am trying to make font-awesome work in SVG without having to resort to re-encoding all the chars as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984007/how-do-i-include-a-font-awesome-icon-in-my-svg), and inestead by just adding the right class to the element.

In other words, I'd like to be able to do this:

```
<tspan
   class="fa fa-meetup"
   x="12.70"
   y="17"></tspan></text>
```

and see it work.

Comment: I do not believe that SVG supports pseudo-elements as yet. - https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/styling.html

Comment: check this may be helpful -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026458/css-before-on-inline-svg

Comment: @SumitPatel that's not really related to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to add the SVG as a background to the psuedo class, avoiding any clashing with SVG as per this post:

[Is there a way to use SVG as content in a pseudo element :before or :after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255296/is-there-a-way-to-use-svg-as-content-in-a-pseudo-element-before-or-after)

So instead of trying to apply the FontAwesome class as a selector on the element, you can set the `i` element to wherever you need it, and compensate for the background SVG that is loaded in.

And to answer your comment - you would need to encode the FA into new classes to make it work the way you're asking, since FontAwesome uses `i` by default. It would work like this:

```
.your-class {
   content: "/f121";
}
```