# Before pseudo element not showing up on path element

Tags: css, svg, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

Hi i am trying to create a 'pin' on a SVG map of the whole world, the SVG is build with path elements, my thought was to use a before or after element and show the pin accordingly.

Apparently it is not showing on the path element, i can see it in the debugger/console and if i put it on a div element it works fine and shows up, i have cut out all countries except the first one in the SVG for simplicity.

CSS

```
.map-pin::after{
    content: url('pin.svg');
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 10;
    font-size: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -999px;
    top: -999px;
    /*display: none;*/
 }

.map-pin.active::after{
    display: block;
}

.map-pin.active[data-id="AF"]::after{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

SVG

```
<svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" style="stroke-linejoin: round; stroke:#000; fill: none;" viewBox="0 0 2000 1001" id="svg2" inkscape:version="0.48.4 r9939" sodipodi:docname="world.svg">
            <defs id="defs4">
                <style type="text/css" id="style6">path { fill-rule: evenodd; }</style>
            </defs>
            <g id="countries">
                <path id="AF" data-name="Afghanistan" data-id="AF" class="map-pin active" d="m 1369.9,333.8 -5.4,0 -3.8,-0.5 -2.5,2.9 -2.1,0.7 -1.5,1.3 -2.6,-2.1 -1,-5.4 -1.6,-0.3 0,-2 -3.2,-1.5 -1.7,2.3 0.2,2.6 -0.6,0.9 -3.2,-0.1 -0.9,3 -2.1,-1.3 -3.3,2.1 -1.8,-0.8 -4.3,-1.4 -2.9,0 -1.6,-0.2 -2.9,-1.7 -0.3,2.3 -4.1,1.2 0.1,5.2 -2.5,2 -4,0.9 -0.4,3 -3.9,0.8 -5.9,-2.4 -0.5,8 -0.5,4.7 2.5,0.9 -1.6,3.5 2.7,5.1 1.1,4 4.3,1.1 1.1,4 -3.9,5.8 9.6,3.2 5.3,-0.9 3.3,0.8 0.9,-1.4 3.8,0.5 6.6,-2.6 -0.8,-5.4 2.3,-3.6 4,0 0.2,-1.7 4,-0.9 2.1,0.6 1.7,-1.8 -1.1,-3.8 1.5,-3.8 3,-1.6 -3,-4.2 5.1,0.2 0.9,-2.3 -0.8,-2.5 2,-2.7 -1.4,-3.2 -1.9,-2.8 2.4,-2.8 5.3,-1.3 5.8,-0.8 2.4,-1.2 2.8,-0.7 -1.4,-1.9 z" style="fill:#f2f2f2;fill-rule:evenodd"></path>
</g>
</svg>
```

I also tried a more simple way by just adding an element inside the SVG after all the path elements, but this breaks the whole SVG.

Anyone able to help me out here, is it not possible in SVG path elements? and if so, what other options am i left with?

PIN:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="Layer_1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" viewBox="0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve">
  <style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#454545;stroke-width:18;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
  <g>
    <g id="XMLID_4245_">
      <path class="st0" d="M389.3,208.7c0-73.6-59.7-133.3-133.3-133.3c-73.6,0-133.3,59.7-133.3,133.3     c0,32.6,12.1,62,31.5,85.1l55.3,75.4l46.6,67.5l101.8-142.9C377.2,270.7,389.3,241.2,389.3,208.7z" id="XMLID_4247_"></path>
      <path class="st0" d="M311,170.9L311,170.9c-12.1-11.6-31.7-11.6-43.8,0l-10.9,10.5L245.3,171     c-12.1-11.6-31.7-11.6-43.8,0c-12.1,11.6-12.1,30.4,0,42l54.7,52.5L311,213C323.1,201.4,323.1,182.6,311,170.9z" id="XMLID_4246_"></path>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

[image]

Comment: "inline SVG is treated as an image, and images are replaced elements which are not allowed to have generated content": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026458/css-before-on-inline-svg

Comment: Wow thats sad honestly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've commented you can't have a before pseudo element for a path. However in your case you can have a symbol for the pin and use it at the end of your document. This way it will stay above all the other paths. (a z-index won't work either in SVG).

If you are using a `symbol` with a `viewBox` attribute you can give the `<use>` element a position (`x` and `y` attributes) and a size (`width` and `height` attributes)

```html
<svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" style="stroke-linejoin: round; stroke:#000; fill: none;" viewBox="1280 320 100 100" id="svg2" >
            <defs id="defs4">
                <style type="text/css" id="style6">path { fill-rule: evenodd; }</style>
            </defs>
  
  <symbol id="map-pin-after" viewBox="0 0 30 30">
    <circle cx="15" cy="8" r="8" />  <polygon points="15,30 22.7,10 7.3,10 15,30"/>
  </symbol>
            <g id="countries">
                <path id="AF" data-name="Afghanistan" data-id="AF" class="map-pin active" d="m 1369.9,333.8 -5.4,0 -3.8,-0.5 -2.5,2.9 -2.1,0.7 -1.5,1.3 -2.6,-2.1 -1,-5.4 -1.6,-0.3 0,-2 -3.2,-1.5 -1.7,2.3 0.2,2.6 -0.6,0.9 -3.2,-0.1 -0.9,3 -2.1,-1.3 -3.3,2.1 -1.8,-0.8 -4.3,-1.4 -2.9,0 -1.6,-0.2 -2.9,-1.7 -0.3,2.3 -4.1,1.2 0.1,5.2 -2.5,2 -4,0.9 -0.4,3 -3.9,0.8 -5.9,-2.4 -0.5,8 -0.5,4.7 2.5,0.9 -1.6,3.5 2.7,5.1 1.1,4 4.3,1.1 1.1,4 -3.9,5.8 9.6,3.2 5.3,-0.9 3.3,0.8 0.9,-1.4 3.8,0.5 6.6,-2.6 -0.8,-5.4 2.3,-3.6 4,0 0.2,-1.7 4,-0.9 2.1,0.6 1.7,-1.8 -1.1,-3.8 1.5,-3.8 3,-1.6 -3,-4.2 5.1,0.2 0.9,-2.3 -0.8,-2.5 2,-2.7 -1.4,-3.2 -1.9,-2.8 2.4,-2.8 5.3,-1.3 5.8,-0.8 2.4,-1.2 2.8,-0.7 -1.4,-1.9 z" fill="#f2f2f2"></path>
</g>
  
  <use xlink:href="#map-pin-after" stroke="none" fill="red" width="30" height="30"  x="1310" y="327"/>
</svg>
```

#### UPDATE

An update where I'm using the OP's pin:

Since the new pin is not a square, and in order to preserve the aspect ratio, I had to recalculate the height of the pin.

```html
<svg viewBox="1280 320 100 100" >
<defs>
<symbol id="map-pin-after" viewBox="111 60 290 397">
    <g id="XMLID_4245_" fill="none" stroke="#454545" stroke-width="18" stroke-mitterlimit="10">
      <path d="M389.3,208.7c0-73.6-59.7-133.3-133.3-133.3c-73.6,0-133.3,59.7-133.3,133.3     c0,32.6,12.1,62,31.5,85.1l55.3,75.4l46.6,67.5l101.8-142.9C377.2,270.7,389.3,241.2,389.3,208.7z" ></path>
      <path  d="M311,170.9L311,170.9c-12.1-11.6-31.7-11.6-43.8,0l-10.9,10.5L245.3,171     c-12.1-11.6-31.7-11.6-43.8,0c-12.1,11.6-12.1,30.4,0,42l54.7,52.5L311,213C323.1,201.4,323.1,182.6,311,170.9z" ></path>
    </g>
  </symbol>
  </defs>
  <g id="countries">
    <path id="AF" data-name="Afghanistan" data-id="AF" class="map-pin active" d="m 1369.9,333.8 -5.4,0 -3.8,-0.5 -2.5,2.9 -2.1,0.7 -1.5,1.3 -2.6,-2.1 -1,-5.4 -1.6,-0.3 0,-2 -3.2,-1.5 -1.7,2.3 0.2,2.6 -0.6,0.9 -3.2,-0.1 -0.9,3 -2.1,-1.3 -3.3,2.1 -1.8,-0.8 -4.3,-1.4 -2.9,0 -1.6,-0.2 -2.9,-1.7 -0.3,2.3 -4.1,1.2 0.1,5.2 -2.5,2 -4,0.9 -0.4,3 -3.9,0.8 -5.9,-2.4 -0.5,8 -0.5,4.7 2.5,0.9 -1.6,3.5 2.7,5.1 1.1,4 4.3,1.1 1.1,4 -3.9,5.8 9.6,3.2 5.3,-0.9 3.3,0.8 0.9,-1.4 3.8,0.5 6.6,-2.6 -0.8,-5.4 2.3,-3.6 4,0 0.2,-1.7 4,-0.9 2.1,0.6 1.7,-1.8 -1.1,-3.8 1.5,-3.8 3,-1.6 -3,-4.2 5.1,0.2 0.9,-2.3 -0.8,-2.5 2,-2.7 -1.4,-3.2 -1.9,-2.8 2.4,-2.8 5.3,-1.3 5.8,-0.8 2.4,-1.2 2.8,-0.7 -1.4,-1.9 z" fill="#f2f2f2" stroke="black"></path>
</g>
  
  <use xlink:href="#map-pin-after" stroke="none" fill="red" width="41" height="30"  x="1305" y="327"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: There is no way i can use my SVG pin? :) i paid money for that, and its a special type of pin :)

Comment: I don't know. I should be able to see your pin

Comment: You are my new hero, thanks a lot its one of the first times i work with SVG's in this way :) thats actually amazingly cool, and the pin is using the DRY principle, thanks man so cool :)